# What do Southen Baptists believe about Jesus' dual nature?

Tags: hypostatic-union, southern-baptist

It's Catholic Dogma that Jesus was one man with two natures.  I was reading an answer to a question on this site where a brother in Christ of the Southern Baptist persuasion was talking about "the man Jesus". Is this just a figure of speech or does it hearken back to the days of Arius when it was fashionable to talk about Jesus being sometimes God?

Comment: While some individuals will always have different beliefs, I don't know of any non-Chalcedonian protestants.

Comment: Well that's good, but I'd imagine it unlikely that everyone subscribes to the Catholic understanding of that Council.  Its often in the aftermath of the councils where the action lies.

Answer (score 2):

Your question may have been in response to one of or possibly more of my answers, and so I have taken the liberty of giving you my understanding, based on my years of Southern Baptist teaching. I cannot speak for the Southern Baptist Conference since I have not personally studied all of their doctrines and you must understand that what I say is based on my years under the tutelage of Southern Baptist ministers and laymen.

That having been said, the concept of Jesus Christ in his tenure on Earth which as I understand it is that Jesus, in his Deity, is Spirit, and existed from Eternity as is said in:

> John 1:1 and 2  In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. 2  The same was in the beginning with God.

And this Spirit being did voluntarily, in response to the desire of the Father, came to Earth, inhabited a human body, lived and died, and physically rose from the dead; to atone for our sins. This was done because God (the Trinity, father son and Holy Ghost); also known as the Godhead, so loved his creation; both human and animal; that they were willing that the son of God suffer and die then rise again to eternal life; so that man might also rise from his fallen state to be given God's great grace of again obtaining eternal life in God's Kingdom as in the words of Jesus himself:

> John 3:16  For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.

That is how I understand Southern Baptist concept of Jesus. As far as speaking of the man Jesus, my intent there was and is to conceptualize that human body as separate from the Deity which is the Spirit Christ (the son of God).

Of this concept I am confident; Christ (the Spirit being) came down from Heaven to inhabit an earthly body which was born of the virgin Mary.

This is my interpretation of the Scriptures based on what I understand, was a separate creation of God in the form of the Holy Spirit, and placed in Mary's womb to be born in human flesh. That Human flesh had all of the characteristics of any other human. and differed from us only in that he was blessed with the mind and will of the Spirit which is a third part of the Trinity and exists for all eternity in the form of the son of God.

It is central to my belief; as I understand Southern Baptist doctrine, That Jesus (the man or the physical body that Jesus inhabited), physically rose from the dead in eternal life and physically ascended into Heaven, where he now sits at the right hand of the Father making intercession for us against the accusations of Satan.

There is much more to my concept of Southern Baptist Doctrine, but that pretty well covers my understanding of Jesus the man.

Perhaps someone more versed in Southern Baptist Doctrine can correct any misgivings I have espoused.

I must thank you for your question as it has given me cause to study the Southern Baptist doctrine further so that I will be less likely to give someone a false concept.

All Scripture is quoted from the King James translation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this not the Catholic teaching?

Comment: @Onlyheisgood. I cannot say whether it is or is not the Catholic teaching since I am unaware as to what the Catholic church teaches about it.

Comment: Catholic,  Baptist,  methodist,  whatever. It's a key pillar in Christianity in general. Every Christian faction has a hand full of core understandings,  and this is the top one. With out this,  the organization could not be considered part of the Christian religion.